# Displaying a field of an entitiy reference

Tags: entities, display-suite

In my *Page* content type there is an `image field` called gallery, and an [`Entity reference`](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field refering to a **related** page.

I need to display the images contained in the gallery field of the **related** page.

I have created a Display Suite a code field. In the tokens I found `[node:field-related-page:field_gallery]` but it seems to be empty (it prints nothing).

I have used Devel's `dpm()` method to display `$entity`'s content but it does the related page fields do not contain any info about the gallery (which makes sense as recursion could be an issue):

[image]

Comment: Side note, you can ignore the 'recursion' notice in `dpm()`, it just means that the same object has already been outputted earlier on in the Krumo display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it only in code, do a `node_load($node->field_related_page['und']['0']['target_id']`. If you want a view, use a relationship and show gallery field with the relationship.